# using jenkins shell invokes python issues sshpass command not found

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

im using jenkins on MAC to make CI environment and encounter this issue.
log on jenkins console output:

```
sh: sshpass: command not found
```

my jenkins shell

```
python $path_python_script"/copy.py"
```

copy.py

```
import os
import ssh
import paramiko
import shutil
import sys
cmmd = "sshpass -p *** scp -r /srcpath username@10.130.***.***:/destpath"
os.system(cmmd)
```

however when i execute the python file on terminal, it definitely works.

appreciate any help.

Comment: `echo $PATH` in the Jenkins shell and your terminal, compare the two. Or do `which sshpass` to find out where it’s located, and adjust your `PATH` or your command accordingly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thx i've tried it and reset the PATH and now it works

Comment: Awesome, I’ll write quick answer so that this question gets marked as “answered” in the overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an application can be executed in the terminal but can’t be found when invoked via a script on the same machine, most of the times the issue is the [`PATH` environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/284342/2269), which is where applications are searched.

The problem can be solved either

1. by adjusting the `PATH` environment variable in the calling script, or
2. by specifying the full path when invoking the binary.

Either way, you will need to figure out where the application is located, by executing (in the terminal)

```sh
which sshpass
```

The result is the full path to the `sshpass` exucutable. You can now use that inside your `cmmd` variable in the script, or you can leave `cmmd` as-is, and adjust `PATH` before invoking it:

```py
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path_to_sshpass
```

Make sure to use the *directory name*, not the full path. That is, if the full path is `/usr/local/bin/sshpass`, then `path_to_sshpass` should be `'/usr/local/bin'`.